# Where I can see the pig map-reduce job failure

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I am running a pig script in -hcatalogue mode and it is failing at the map reduce job execution. It says one of the map reduce job is failing. What would be the best way to troubleshoot. i am trying to find the log file but i could not get it. 
Is there any specific place i can find the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log of pig-script is created in the working directory from where you have run the pig script or started the pig-console.

For Map-Reduce log you have to check the `[HADOOP_HOME]/logs/userlogs` directory. you will get ERROR message either in sysout file or syserr file.

Comment: Thank you for answer.. I am facing difficult in getting the value of my hadoop_home variable. Do you know where can I find them. looks like those are  not set

Comment: HADOOP_HOME variable is not set by default. You have to set it manually to the location where you have extracted the hadoop-xxxx.tar.gz file. If you are running Pig in local mode i.e. `pig -x local` then you don't need to set HADOOP_HOME variable.